# Ajax call to ColdFusion component not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to make an Ajax call with jQuery to my ColdFusion component within QueryData.cfc

Here is the QueryData.cfc code:

```
<cfcomponent name="querydata" access="remote" hint="getting data from SQL database">
    <cffunction name="QueryData_Pt" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfquery NAME="GrabData_Pt" DATASOURCE="#Application.PrimaryDataSource#" cachedWithin = "#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,1,0)#">
            //code;
        </cfquery>
        <cfloop query="GrabData_Pt">
            <cfset Pd_data=serializeJSON(GrabData_Pt)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn GrabData_Pt>
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="QueryData_Pd" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfquery NAME="GrabData_Pd" DATASOURCE="#Application.PrimaryDataSource#" cachedWithin = "#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,1,0)#">
            //code
        </cfquery>
        <cfloop query="GrabData_Pd">
            <cfset Pd_data=serializeJSON(GrabData_Pd)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn GrabData_Pd>
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="QueryData_Rh" returntype="any" access="remote" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfquery NAME="GrabData_Rh" DATASOURCE="#Application.PrimaryDataSource#" cachedWithin = "#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,1,0)#">
            //somecode
        </cfquery>
        <cfloop query="GrabData_Rh">
            <cfset Rh_data=serializeJSON(GrabData_Rh)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn Rh_data>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The problem I am having is that nothing is being returned. I've dumped the component data and the query is working as expected so it's not that, but for some reason the data is flowing to my .cfm file. I'm sure something is wrong with the jQuery so here is that code now:

```
var pt_var;
var pd_var;
var rh_var;
var pt_array = [];
var pd_array = [];
var rh_array = [];

$(function() {
    getdatafromquery();

    function getdatafromquery() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // this
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'QueryData.cfc',
        data: {
          method: 'QueryData_Pt'
        }
      }).done(function(pt_data) {
        pt_var = pt_data;

      });
    }
```

I then use that data and plot it using highcharts. I can see that nothing is being passed via the Google Chrome DevTools. Hopefully it's clear what I am doing wrong. I'm new to jQuery and Ajax and ColdFusion so this is a huge learning curve for me haha. Any and all help is really appreciated!

EDIT:

Turns out I wasn't serializing into json. However, now that it's being passed it's passing each cell as an individual array. Here's an example:

```
DATA
:
Array(79)
0:[498]
1:[494]
2:[496]
3:[494]
4:[498]
5:[495]
```

Comment: Is the AJAX call hitting your ColdFusion server? Can you see that the function is being called? Also, you don't need to loop over the query and `serializeJSON()` each iteration. You can just serialize on the return, like `<cfreturn serializeJSON(GrabData_Pt)>`.

Comment: Your function seems to loop over the query and do nothing with it. Do you mean to return the serialised JSON string not the query object?

Comment: Yeah, I'm basically just trying to return the data from the query into a JSON format for the Ajax call

Comment: Right now I'm getting an error saying `cant read property push of undefined`. I can't see the function being called, I don't really know how too

Comment: I would just stick to the Ajax request. Add a fail function as it's most likely not running the done part. Use Google dev tools and breakpoint each section to see where it stops and check the data. Or console.log the data returned. Likely the Ajax request fails because incorrect JSON is being returned. Serialise the query object on the return.

Comment: Fantastic! That parsed the right data, but it's turning each row into it's own array. I updated the question to show some results

Comment: @G.Rose have a quick look at the serializejson docs. CF 11 and above can set the query format and you can set it to struct.

Comment: @haxtbh thank you for your help! On a topic unrelated to the original question, does createtimespan actually run a query every minute if that's what I need it to do?

Comment: @G.Rose this simply tells the engine how long to cache the query before it requests it again from the database.

Comment: @haxtbh basically like an expatriation date? Would this achieve updating data every minute if were to append the results from the ajax call to an array?

Comment: Caching won't update data. It'll just make sure that if the query is called again within the cache time, that it won't make another trip to the database to get new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the way your query is outputting here is what i do; I defined a query so that you can see how its called in the loop:

```
    <cffunction name="QueryData_Pt" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">
   <cfset retVal = ArrayNew(1)>

       <cfquery NAME="results" DATASOURCE="#Application.PrimaryDataSource#" cachedWithin = "#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,1,0)#">
        SELECT DEPARTMENTNAME,DEPTID,EMPLID,WORKPHONE,FULL_NAME,EMAIL_ADDRESS,LOCATION
    </cfquery>

      <cfloop query="results">
       <cfset temp = {} />
       <cfset temp['DEPARTMENTNAME']=DEPARTMENTNAME />
        <cfset temp['DEPARTMENTID']=DEPTID />
        <cfset temp['EMPLID']=EMPLID />
        <cfset temp['WORKPHONE']=WORKPHONE />
        <cfset temp['FULL_NAME']=FULL_NAME />
        <cfset temp['EMAIL_ADDRESS']=EMAIL_ADDRESS />
        <cfset temp['LOCATION']=LOCATION />
    <cfset ArrayAppend(retval, temp)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfset result = {} />
    <cfset result['items'] = retVal />
    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

In the ajax I call the cfc and in the success I create a var x=items.data so I can call the data in this way x[0].DEPARTMENTNAME or if in a for loop `for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)` x[i].DEPARTMENTNAME.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot

Comment: NP let me know if you need me to post the $.ajax

Comment: Thank you, I got it though turns out it's pretty simple haha

Comment: Don't forget to localize *all* function variables.

Answer (score 3):

Using remote .cfc methods introduces some problems in my experience. They are a bit trickier to debug and they open up attack vectors into your .cfc files, which typically contain all your application logic. ACF has fixed several security issues with remote methods in .cfc files, and to me it doesn't feel right to allow remote calls into my application logic.

Instead, I keep my application logic separated from the front end. Front-end code is accessible from the web root (typically `/project_name/www/`), while other application layers would be located outside this directory - e.g. `/project_name/cfusion/cfc/` or `project_name/lib/stripe/stripe.cfc`.

An alternative and effective approach for handling ajax requests is as follows: I use .cfm files located inside the web root, which in turn make calls into my CFCs. The main benefit is code separation and debugging.

Here's a sample template, I'll name it `/test.cfm`:

```
<cfscript>
setting showdebugoutput=false;
header name="Content-Type" value="application/json";

try {

    param name="url.param1" type="numeric";
    param name="url.param2" type="numeric";

} catch (any e) {
    writeOutput(serializeJSON({
        "error": "Invalid request", 
        "errorCode": -1
    }));
    abort;
}

r = {
    "errorCode": 0,
    "error": ""
};

try {

    // create and call your cfc code here
    myCFC = createObject("cfc.something").init(url.param1);
    r = myCFC.doSomething();

} catch (any e) {

    // insert your own error handling here

    param name="errorCode" default=-1;

    r.errorCode = errorCode;
    r.error = e.message & " " & e.detail; 

}

writeOutput(serializeJSON(r));
</cfscript>
```

Then, from the browser, you would make your ajax call using jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test.cfm',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        param1: 4,
        param2: 90
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
        alert('an error occurred');
    }
});
```

Comment: I would accept this as an answer as well, thank you for the tip. That is very helpful!

Comment: Obviously the scope would change for the parameters in the ajax handler if you are making a `get` or `post` request. `get` requests pass the parameters into your ajax handler using the `url` scope and `post` requests pass the parameters via the `form` scope.

Comment: that really threw me off initially because one source I read from was saying that POST was how you get information to your ajax call. I knew HTTP methods are universal so that slowed me down a bit, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Thor4x's answer, I use this

```
for (i in getQuery.columnList) {
  ret.q[i] = QueryColumnData(getQuery, i);
}
```

I loop over getQuery.columnList and use `QueryColumnData()`. The result is a JSON object structured almost like a cold fusion query. Except that it's a structure of arrays `ajaxReturn.key[index]` rather than an array of structures. `ajaxReturn[index].key`

You could, as they have, specify the columns manually, or use an IF to filter out certain keys.

In Lucee at least (and likely ACF, since Lucee aims to be consistent with ACF), meta values like `recordcount` and `columnList` itself are not in `query.columnList`. If you want those copied, you only need a manual assigment after the loop.

`ret.q.recordcount = getQuery.recordcount;`